# Why is my text overlapping in my navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out why the text is not centered in the box or why it's overlapping.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTd5k.png

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(187, 190, 4);
  font-family: Arial;
}

.navBAr,
ul {
  list-style: none;
  background: #401f99;
  padding: 0%;
  margin: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  white-space: normal;
}

.navBar,
li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar,
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.navBar,
a:hover {
  background: rgb(84, 109, 221);
}
```

```html
<div id="navBar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">HomePage</a></li>
    <li><a href="/mainPages/googleForm.html">Google Form</a></li>
    <li><a href="/mainPages/myMovies.html">Movies</a></li>
    <li><a href="/mainPages/myTvShows.html">Shows</a></li>
    <li><a href="/mainPages/topMovies.html">Top Movies</a></li>
    <li><a href="/mainPages/topTvShows.html">Top Shows</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a specific set width for the links, 100px, so any text will overflow. Remove the width:100px; and you should be all set.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(187, 190, 4);
  font-family: Arial;
}

.navBAr,
ul {
  list-style: none;
  background: #401f99;
  padding: 0%;
  margin: 0%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  white-space: normal;
}

.navBar,
li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar,
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  /* width:100px; */
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.navBar,
a:hover {
  background: rgb(84, 109, 221);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Movie And Tv Shows Google Form Recomendations</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="background.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="navBar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">HomePage</a></li>
        <li><a href="/mainPages/googleForm.html">Google Form</a></li>
        <li><a href="/mainPages/myMovies.html">Movies</a></li>
        <li><a href="/mainPages/myTvShows.html">Shows</a></li>
        <li><a href="/mainPages/topMovies.html">Top Movies</a></li>
        <li><a href="/mainPages/topTvShows.html">Top Shows</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```